# Inserting client certificates into an HTTPS POST request

Tags: ssl, arduino-ide, aws-iot

I'm building a hardware device which connects to the AWS IOT platform. According to the documentation the authentication with the aws iot platform is done with TLS. I have the Root CA, client key and client certificate files on the device that authorize the access. Is there a way to use these files in the HTTP header while making the POST request? If so, how? So far here is the code for the Energia IDE (based on the Arduino IDE) and using the WiFiClient methods.

```
if (client.sslConnect(aws_endpoint, 443))
{
  Serial.println("\nConnected to AWS endpoint");

  String PostData = "{\"value1\" : \"testValue\", \"value2\" : \"Hello\", \"value3\" : \"World!\" }";

  request = "POST /things/";
  request += thingname;
  request += "/shadow";
  request += " HTTP/1.1";
  Serial.print("Request:\t"); Serial.println(request);
  Serial.print("Post data:\t"); Serial.println(PostData);

  client.println(request);
  client.println("Host: ");
  client.println(aws_endpoint);
  client.println(":443");
  client.println("User-Agent: Energia/1.1");
  client.println("Connection: close");
  client.println("Content-Type: application/json");
  client.print("Content-Length: "); client.println(PostData.length());
  client.println();
  client.println(PostData);
  client.println();
}
else
{
  Serial.println("Connection failed");
}

Serial.println(); 
Serial.println("Server response:"); 
Serial.println(); 

// Capture response from the server. (10 second timeout)
long timeOut = 5000;
long lastTime = millis();

while((millis()-lastTime) < timeOut)
{ // Wait for incoming response from server
  while (client.available()) 
  { // Characters incoming from the server
    char c = client.read();            // Read characters
    Serial.write(c);
  }
}
```

This however, gives an authentication error:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
content-type: application/json
content-length: 91
date: Tue, 26 Jul 2016 11:46:59 GMT
x-amzn-RequestId: 4d5388a9-e3c4-460a-b674-c3f971f3330d
connection: Keep-Alive
x-amzn-ErrorType: ForbiddenException:

{"message":"Missing Authentication Token","traceId":"4d5388a9-e3c4-460a-b674-c3f971f3330d"}
```

Comment: The TLS client certificates would be sent/used as part of your `client.sslConnect()` call, not as part of the HTTP request.  The TLS handshake (and exchange/validation of client and server certificates) happens _before_ any HTTP message is sent.

Comment: Now that I think of it, I guess thats why the connection is successful in the first place. Then whats the "Missing Authentication Token" error? and how do I fix this?

Comment: Good question.  [This AWS forums post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=221078) suggests that you _may_ need to be using port 8443 (not port 443), for the shadow API.  I would also suggest that you double-check that your `client.println()` function appends CRLF, not just LF, to the end of the strings (as HTTP requires CRLF line terminations.

Comment: Thanks! that actually helped. I changed the port to 8443 and it worked!

Comment: Perfect.  I've written up my comments as an actual answer, for future readers. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TLS client certificates would be sent/used as part of your `client.sslConnect()` call, **not** as part of the HTTP request. The TLS handshake (and exchange/validation of client and server certificates) happens before any HTTP message is sent.

[This AWS forums post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=221078) suggests that you may need to be using port 8443 (*not* port 443), for the shadow API.  It looks like the use/requirement of TLS mutual authentication (via certificates), *versus* the use of AWS SIGv4 headers, is determined by AWS IOT based on the port used.

Hope this helps!